# Drupal Commerce payment transaction: execute script and pass variables

Tags: commerce

When you need to create a new transaction method for Drupal Commerce, you need to dive into the code. And that's something I have zero experience with. BUT the following couldn't be hard. I already created a new payment module (just copied and edited the payment example module so I have a new payment method).

In `commerce_payment_example.module` you have the function `commerce_payment_ideal_transaction` that is been executed by the submit button of the checkout form. The only thing I need to do is to execute a script on submit (in HTML you can do this with `<form method="post" action="script.php">`, and pass three variables with it: the amount `($charge ?)`, the order ID `($order->order_id ?)` and a description `($order ?)`. Could someone help me on the right way?

Comment: I don't know about you, but commerce payment methods are about money. I would *totally* not be comfortable running a payment method that is hacked by yourself when you have zero experience with programming.

Answer (score 1):

the transaction is meant to be created on a successful response of your provider (this could be payed, denied or whatever), usually an IPN.
meaning you have to provide a **MENU_CALLBACK** item in `hook_menu`.
most likely information about the order will be posted, make sure you get the order id back.

if you really want that on the payment form submission, just call the method (`commerce_payment_ideal_transaction`) in the `hook_redirect_form`. the question here is, how do you decide if a payment was successful or not ;)